# Unable to send youtube video link to whats app as text message

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, url-scheme

code working fine with other links but not wit youtube link specially when link contains Video ID...

```
    NSString*str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://youtube.com/watch?v=%@",myVideoId];

    NSString*Wastring2=[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@",str];

    NSURL *whatsappURL =  [NSURL URLWithString:Wastring2];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [whatsappURL absoluteURL]]) {
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [whatsappURL absoluteURL]];
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode your youtube URL.

```
  NSString*str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://youtube.com/watch?v%3D%@",myVideoId];
```

Comment: " youtube.com/watch?v=id " if I remove " = " sign then it works

Comment: what is the `NSLog` of `escapedUrlString` ?

Comment: try replacing = with %3D if only = is an issue, see my edited answer. It looks like stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding is only replacing space and a few characters actually

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have tested the youtube link and now it works with the code below you only have to add percentage escape `?v=` to `?v%%3D`

be careful there have to be two %% to escape the string manually

```
  NSString*str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://youtube.com/watch?v%%3D%@",myVideoID];
str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@",str];
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
}
```